# search display controller update table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm making an app, which destination iOS is 7.0. So I use search display controller. When i try to search, i make an api request, and it's results are coming later, than search display controller updates table view. So it's empty, though i have results of search. I've tried something like

```
self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
```

straight after reaching data from request, but it's not working.

Here is my logic:

```
  func filterContextForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    BooksWorker.searchForBooks(searchText) { foundBooks in
      self.foundBooks = foundBooks
      if BooksWorker.books != nil {
        self.filteredBooks = BooksWorker.books.filter { book in
          return (book.name?.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString))!
        }
      }
      self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String?) -> Bool {
    isSearch = true
    filterContextForSearchText(searchString!)
    return true
  }
```

I update my tableView in such a way:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if isSearch {
      tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
      return filteredBooks.count
    } else {
      if BooksWorker.books != nil {
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine
        return (BooksWorker.books?.count)!
      } else {
        showEmptyTableView()
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
        return 0
      }
    }
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if isSearch {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AppData.CellIdentifiers.UndownloadedBookCell) as! UndownloadedBookCell
      print("making cell")
      cell.setBook(foundBooks[indexPath.row])
      cell.delegate = self
      return cell
    } else {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AppData.CellIdentifiers.BookCell) as! BookCell
      cell.setBook(BooksWorker.books![indexPath.row])
      return cell
    }
  }
```

Does anybody having an idea?

Comment: did you set the `searchResultsDataSource ` ?

Comment: [screenschot](https://pp.vk.me/c631529/v631529270/11023/IwJ4YOd2yE4.jpg) is all right here? Biblioteca is my table view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should update tableView not searchDisplay `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: It didn't help, search result is still empty

Comment: can you debug `filteredBooks.count` and see if it is changed ?

Comment: It's changing. I've replaced `self.foundBooks = foundBooks` with `self.foundBooks.removeAll(); self.foundBooks.appendContentsOf(foundBooks)` in searchForBooksclosure and noticed this [sceenshot](https://pp.vk.me/c631529/v631529270/11010/GfGEi8BAcIo.jpg) . it displays empty cells under empty tableView with "No result"

Comment: can you post where you are settings delegates of the `searchDisplayController ` ?

Comment: did you check if you get something from the filter closure ? i have attached an example of project with the same situation and i am simulating the api call with a timeout timer check it it should help you find a solution https://mega.nz/#!DsUhFCCQ

Comment: i've finally found it! In number of rows in section if isSearch i return count of filteredBooks instead of count of foundBooks :)